# gridview model binding and sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the below GridView on a page which I'm using Model Binding to get the data into.

```
                <asp:GridView ID="grdvAppType" DataKeyNames="ApplicationTypeSeqid" runat="server" ItemType="MyType.ApplicationType"
                AutoGenerateColumns="false" SelectMethod="GetAppliationTypes" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" AllowSorting="true">
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    No records
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type Name" SortExpression="TypeName">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Item.TypeName %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

There are other columns, but i've removed them here.  The code behind has the SelectMethod set as:

```
        public List<MyType.ApplicationType> GetAppliationTypes(int startRowIndex, int maximumRows, out int totalRowCount)
    {
        List<MyType.ApplicationType> lstAppType = null;
        using (ApplicationTypeRepository appTypeRepos = new ApplicationTypeRepository(new UnitOfWork()))
        {
            totalRowCount = appTypeRepos.All.Where(x => x.isActive).Count();
            var data = appTypeRepos.All.Where(x => x.isActive).OrderBy(x => x.TypeName).Skip(startRowIndex).Take(maximumRows);
            lstAppType = data.ToList();
        }

        return lstAppType;
    }
```

This works fine, as i'm retrieving just the records I want per page, rather than getting all the data every time I move from page to page.  But I'm not sure how to get this to work with sorting, for example, if I wanted the TypeName column to be sortable.  What do I need to look for in the SelectMethod to see what option was selected to sort by, if nothing is chosen it should default to the TypeName?

Answer (score 0):

In WPF I'm using the DataGrid for auto-sorting and it works fine for me but I don't know if it's available for ASP.NET too . I also found this article, check it out , I think that it's what you're searching for . Hope it helps! 
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.allowsorting(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: DataGrid i don't think is available anymore in asp.net, i'm using 4.5.  We do have a Gridview, which is what I'm using.  There is a way to get it to work but that means using IQueryable, which is something I want to avoid as we have a service layer which is sending the data back, so i want to avoid sending the IQueryable back through the service.

Answer (score 0):

there is another argument to the SelectMethod call called "sortExpression".  It will give you the field being sorted.

```
public List<MyType.ApplicationType> GetAppliationTypes(string sortExpression, 
                   int startRowIndex, int maximumRows, out int totalRowCount)
```